# Error while calling sql from unix shell script

Tags: unix, oracle11g

I have a shell script running on unix. Like this:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s '/ as sysdba' <<EOF
set head on; 
set feed on;
set serveroutput on;
set linesize 250;   
set pagesize 1000;
column STATUS new_value VAR_STATUS ;
column JOB_NAME new_value VAR_JOB_NAME ;
BEGIN
SELECT JOB_NAME, STATUS
FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS WHERE JOB_NAME = 'SOME_JOB' AND ACTUAL_START_DATE IN (SELECT MAX(ACTUAL_START_DATE) FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS);

END;

/
exit
EOF
```

I get error:

```
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One thing you might try is replacing the invocation of sqlplus with the `cat` command. Redirect output to a file and look at the results to see if the output is not what you expected.

Comment: Thanks. But what is wrong with this syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I do stuff like this I don't use BEGIN and END statements.  Think of the redirected input as exactly the same as you typing this from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

When you use begin and end Oracle will treat as Anonymous procedure and expect variable declaration and into clause to assign the values into variables.

Remove the begin and End and try.
If you want Begin End then declare the variables of respective datatype and try.